# Why `bundle exec rake test` hang in Ubuntu 19.10 (PopOS)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, testing

I joined a development team and I have a project in ruby ​​(2.6.5) on rails (6) to which we are adding tests to increase coverage with simplecov. The problem is moving from the Mac CatalinaOS environment to Ubuntu.

We use the asdf version manager we have all the dependencies installed locally, the database also, redis and sidekiq the same. The project can be executed; but nevertheless, when wanting to run the tests with `bundle exec rake test` Ubuntu gets stuck after running some tests.

We have tested by uninstalling the ruby, node and yarn versions. Reinstalling everything, and even reinstalling PopOS 19.10 and the problem persists. Does anyone know why ruby ​​is hanging in Ubuntu under these conditions??

I am adding the stack trace after CTRL+C with the process hanged for more than 20 min.

[image]

[image]

```
/home/alejandro/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activejob-5.2.4.1/lib/active_job/railtie.rb:28:in `block (4 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
/home/alejandro/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.1/lib/active_support/execution_wrapper.rb:87:in `wrap'
/home/alejandro/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.1/lib/active_support/reloader.rb:73:in `block in wrap'
/home/alejandro/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.1/lib/active_support/execution_wrapper.rb:87:in `wrap'
/home/alejandro/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.1/lib/active_support/reloader.rb:72:in `wrap'
/home/alejandro/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activejob-5.2.4.1/lib/active_job/railtie.rb:27:in `block (3 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
/home/alejandro/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:118:in `instance_exec'
/home/alejandro/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:118:in `block in run_callbacks'
/home/alejandro/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:136:in `run_callbacks'
/home/alejandro/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activejob-5.2.4.1/lib/active_job/execution.rb:22:in `execute'
/home/alejandro/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activejob-5.2.4.1/lib/active_job/queue_adapters/test_adapter.rb:50:in `enqueue_or_perform'
/home/alejandro/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activejob-5.2.4.1/lib/active_job/queue_adapters/test_adapter.rb:32:in `enqueue'
/home/alejandro/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activejob-5.2.4.1/lib/active_job/enqueuing.rb:53:in `block in enqueue'
/home/alejandro/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:109:in `block in run_callbacks'
/home/alejandro/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activejob-5.2.4.1/lib/active_job/logging.rb:17:in `block (3 levels) in <module:Logging>'
/home/alejandro/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activejob-5.2.4.1/lib/active_job/logging.rb:46:in `block in tag_logger'
/home/alejandro/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.1/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:71:in `block in tagged'
/home/alejandro/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.1/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:28:in `tagged'
/home/alejandro/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.1/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:71:in `tagged'
/home/alejandro/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activejob-5.2.4.1/lib/active_job/logging.rb:46:in `tag_logger'
/home/alejandro/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activejob-5.2.4.1/lib/active_job/logging.rb:16:in `block (2 levels) in <module:Logging>'
/home/alejandro/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:118:in `instance_exec'
/home/alejandro/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:118:in `block in run_callbacks'
/home/alejandro/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:136:in `run_callbacks'
/home/alejandro/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activejob-5.2.4.1/lib/active_job/enqueuing.rb:49:in `enqueue'
/home/alejandro/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activejob-5.2.4.1/lib/active_job/enqueuing.rb:20:in `perform_later'
/home/alejandro/EXTRA/REPOS/cartera/test/jobs/expire_installments_job_test.rb:42:in `block in test_it_updates_credit_installments_state_to_more_than_one_expired'
/home/alejandro/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activejob-5.2.4.1/lib/active_job/test_helper.rb:382:in `perform_enqueued_jobs'
/home/alejandro/EXTRA/REPOS/cartera/test/jobs/expire_installments_job_test.rb:41:in `test_it_updates_credit_installments_state_to_more_than_one_expired'
/home/alejandro/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/minitest-5.14.0/lib/minitest/test.rb:98:in `block (3 levels) in run'
/home/alejandro/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/minitest-5.14.0/lib/minitest/test.rb:195:in `capture_exceptions'
/home/alejandro/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/minitest-5.14.0/lib/minitest/test.rb:95:in `block (2 levels) in run'
/home/alejandro/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/minitest-5.14.0/lib/minitest.rb:270:in `time_it'
/home/alejandro/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/minitest-5.14.0/lib/minitest/test.rb:94:in `block in run'
/home/alejandro/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/minitest-5.14.0/lib/minitest.rb:365:in `on_signal'
/home/alejandro/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/minitest-5.14.0/lib/minitest/test.rb:211:in `with_info_handler'
/home/alejandro/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/minitest-5.14.0/lib/minitest/test.rb:93:in `run'
/home/alejandro/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/minitest-5.14.0/lib/minitest.rb:1026:in `run_one_method'
/home/alejandro/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/minitest-5.14.0/lib/minitest.rb:339:in `run_one_method'
/home/alejandro/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/minitest-5.14.0/lib/minitest.rb:326:in `block (2 levels) in run'
/home/alejandro/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/minitest-5.14.0/lib/minitest.rb:325:in `each'
/home/alejandro/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/minitest-5.14.0/lib/minitest.rb:325:in `block in run'
/home/alejandro/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/minitest-5.14.0/lib/minitest.rb:365:in `on_signal'
/home/alejandro/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/minitest-5.14.0/lib/minitest.rb:352:in `with_info_handler'
/home/alejandro/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/minitest-5.14.0/lib/minitest.rb:324:in `run'
/home/alejandro/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.4.1/lib/rails/test_unit/line_filtering.rb:10:in `run'
/home/alejandro/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/minitest-5.14.0/lib/minitest.rb:164:in `block in __run'
/home/alejandro/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/minitest-5.14.0/lib/minitest.rb:164:in `map'
/home/alejandro/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/minitest-5.14.0/lib/minitest.rb:164:in `__run'
/home/alejandro/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/minitest-5.14.0/lib/minitest.rb:141:in `run'
/home/alejandro/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/minitest-5.14.0/lib/minitest.rb:68:in `block in autorun'
```

Comment: What test suite are you using? When it gets "stuck" is it always the same spec?  How long does it run before that?  Can you post your spec helpers / config?  Are you able to run specific test files without hang?  What gems are you using for test? 
It could be anything and without some detail here we can only shoot in the dark.

Comment: I ma using minitest and capybara and simplecov. It is not always in the same test when it gets stuck. How long is variable, some times it only runs 5 test but other it runs a few 100. I can't post any file from the project since it is private and owned by a third party. I'm pretty sure it doesn't have to do anything with the gems since the mac environment is using the same gems. Even the ubuntu laptop is higher in all specs, for instance it has an ssd while the mac is still using hdd. It has to do with ubuntu.

Comment: Are you using docker? Can you build a containerized app to see if the problem persists?

Comment: I have run it inside Docker, Ubuntu base and alpine, the problem does not persist that is why I assume is something about the Distro

Comment: What does "stuck" mean? Does the whole machine freeze, does the command respond to Ctril-C? If it responds to Ctrl-C, then please look at the call stack where it is stuck. Most likely it will be a system call perhaps, which could give a clue as to where the problem is in the distro.

Comment: CTRL+C responds always, it does not hang any other portion of the system. I've added the stack trace after interrupting the process. The process was hanged at least for 20 min and as you can see the console prints a different timing. I don't know where to look, any help is welcome

Comment: Did you check the `log/test.log`? Do you get stuck on a particular test every time? For example, in a test that calls an external API, the IP of the PC you are using is changed and packets are dropped?

Comment: I'll add the tail from the `test.log` ASAP, right now due to the deadline I had to stick with the MacPro. But my team run a live Regolith with all the same setup just to test another distro from Ubuntu, and it ran all the tests with no problems. My guess is that something is wrong in the distro.

Comment: there it is, as I said the test.log file wasn't useful to us but if anyone can help please do

Comment: Please do not post images of plaintext as [they are not appropriate on StackOverflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3784008). Please copy and paste plaintext into your question.

Comment: The images are just to show side by side the tail of the test.log file which is paste in plain text, so the text inside the images is not important for the question. Is just to show that the task gets hanged up at different points

Answer (score -2):

As a workaround, you can manually set `dns_timeout` to any array of numbers. The default should be `[5, 10, 15, 20]`.